# Locker Program... Displaying the method once a button is clicked

Tags: java, output

I am doing the 1000 locker program. I am having one problem though, the code functions and with system.out.println it will display how I want it to display but, in the text area it won't display. Please Help Me, and commenting would be a great help. Thanks in Advance!

```
String output = "";
int numOpen = 0;
String numCount = "";
```

(Above code is declared at top of program)

```
private int runLockers(int Lockers)
{
    final int numLockers = Integer.valueOf(numLockerTextField.getText());
    int numClosed = Integer.valueOf(numLockerTextField.getText());
    boolean lockers[] = new boolean[numLockers+1];

    for(int studentNum = 1; studentNum <= numLockers; studentNum++)
    {
        for(int locker = studentNum; locker <= numLockers; locker+=studentNum)
        {
            lockers[locker]=!lockers[locker];
        }
    }

   for(int count=1; count <= numLockers; count++)
   {
       if(lockers[count])
       {
           numOpen++;
           numCount+="Locker: "+count+"\n";
           System.out.println("Open Lockers:" + numOpen);
           System.out.println(numCount);
           output+="Open Lockers:" + numOpen + numCount;
       }
   }
    //outputTextArea.setText(output);
    return(numOpen);
}

private void simulateBtnActionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    outputTextArea.setText(output);
    outputTextArea.setText("There are "+ Integer.valueOf(numLockerTextField.getText()) +" lockers, and "+ runLockers(0) +" are left open.");
}
```

This is the sumulate button code. It is before the method:

```
simulateButton = new JButton(); //declaring my new JButton
simulateButton.setText("Simulate"); //setting the text of the JButton
simulateButton.setBounds(160,500,100,30); //setting the bounds to which the Button is set to; The int x&y also the width&height
contentPane.add(simulateButton); //adding label to contentPane so it will be visible to user
simulateButton.addActionListener // adding an interface used to listen for an action event
            (
                    new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                        {
                            simulateBtnActionPerformed(event);
                        }
                    } // referencing what action is to be perform when button is pressed
            );
```

Here is an example of how it out prints :

```
Open Lockers:1
Locker: 1

Open Lockers:2
Locker: 1
Locker: 4

Open Lockers:3
Locker: 1
Locker: 4
Locker: 9
```

This is the only line that appears in text area:

outputTextArea.setText("There are "+ Integer.valueOf(numLockerTextField.getText()) +" lockers, and "+ runLockers(0) +" are left open.");

... which looks like

```
There are 1000 lockers, and 31 are left open.
```

This is what the text area SHOULD look like:

```
Open Lockers:1
Locker: 1

Open Lockers:2
Locker: 1
Locker: 4

Open Lockers:3
Locker: 1
Locker: 4
Locker: 9

(.... that goes to 1000)

There are 1000 lockers, and 31 are left open.
```

Comment: Couldn't you use the answers everyone gave you last time you asked this same question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472731/locker-program-using-a-method-need-help-displaying-some-additional-things/21472815?noredirect=1#comment32408729_21472815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the text of `outputTextArea` to `output` and then immediately replacing that with other text (the `"There are ..."` string). You probably want to be appending strings instead of setting the text twice. Maybe something like this:

```
private void simulateBtnActionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    outputTextArea.setText(output
        + "\nThere are "+ Integer.valueOf(numLockerTextField.getText()) +" lockers, and "+ runLockers(0) +" are left open.");
}
```

Comment: I do believe you are correct but, it still didn't display output.

Comment: @TubaShark - Perhaps I misunderstood the symptoms. Does anything at all display?

Comment: output doesn't display... but, There are "+ Integer.valueOf(numLockerTextField.getText()) +" lockers, and "+ runLockers(0) +" are left open."); ... that will display

Comment: @TubaShark - Odd. Try printing the value of `output` from inside `simulateBtnActionPerformed`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. I tried printing output out and it didn't print anything.

Comment: @TubaShark - Then the problem is in the code that calls `simulateBtnActionPerformed`. You haven't shown us that. Is it being called before `runLockers` runs its loop?

Comment: simulateButton.addActionListener // adding an interface used to listen for an action event
                (
                        new ActionListener()
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                            {
                                simulateBtnActionPerformed(event);
                            }
                        } // referencing what action is to be perform when button is pressed
                );

Comment: @TubaShark - Well, that's the problem, evidently. Until `runLockers` executes, `output` will not have any text appended to it. The problem now lies in the control flow for your program, not in the code you posted (once you correct the overwrite problem I pointed out).

Comment: okay and one last question... how would i clear the value of everything and the text area so when i run it, it won't keeping adding on but instead just restarting

Comment: @TubaShark - Just `output = ""; outputTextArea.setText("");`. It might be convenient to package that up into a little method called `clear()` or `reset()`.

Comment: i got it... i just had to add numOpen=0; after i set text of text area in simulateBtnActionPerformed ... Thanks for all your help. It's working perfectly now